# Is this an homework or check-my-work type question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, homework-and-exercises

I recently asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574046/) on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). I wanted to know if this is an homework or check my work type question?

Comment: It might be closed under `Needs details or clarity`.

Comment: The question has been reopened, but I still suggest making the changes I outline in my answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this line

> How can we explain this phenomenon using ray diagrams?

is the issue. At first glance it makes it look like you are just asking for someone to make a ray diagram for you rather than asking about physics concepts here.

An easy fix could be something like

> From ray diagrams it can easily be concluded that using a real object, we cannot get a real image from a plane mirror. But, if we shine a torch on the mirror we see a real image on the wall. Why does a real image form despite ray diagrams showing they do not form?

This puts the focus on understanding what constitutes a real image, and how they relate to ray diagrams.

It might also help to explain why you think it is a real image (and not just light reflecting off a surface), and maybe even your ray diagrams showing how real images do not form.

Comment: Thank you!! That very useful! I will keep that in mind when asking my next question. Also thank you for reopening the question!